# I have a problem creating an API to update images in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I have a problem creating an API to update images in laravel, in the if condition hasFile () data always returns "gagal edit".
i am using laravel 8

```
    $dataproduk = Biodatum::findOrFail($id);
    $dataproduk->name = $request->name;
    $dataproduk->description = $request->description;
    $dataproduk->content = $request->content;
    if ($request->hasFile('picture')) {
        $file = $request->file('picture');
        $path = 'biodata/March2021/' . uniqid() . '.' . $file->extension();
        $file->storePubliclyAs('public', $path);
        $data['picture'] = $path;
        $dataproduk->picture = $path;
        $dataproduk->save();
        return response()->json($dataproduk);
    } else {
        $dataproduk = "gagal edit";
        return response()->json($dataproduk);
    }
```

Comment: That means it's no file on $request->picture input. Check your frontend code.

Comment: Have you added this attribute to your form tag? `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Comment: I use Postman software to update the picture

Comment: if you're using postman, make sure you're not sending json type in request body. please change your body to 'form-data', in your key column, change your type into a file not text, then in key column fill with 'picture' (without quotation marks), then select your file in value column